# Salesforce Sites Authorization Required error for even an empty page

Tags: visualforce, force.com-sites

I'm stuck with an issue - I'm getting **Authorization required** error even for an empty page. Even when I'm clicking "Preview as Admin". It seems i'm missing something simple. Could you, please, give me any thoughts where to look? Thank you in advance!
[image: Authorization required]

VF page ErrorFinder.page:

```
<apex:page>
</apex:page>
```

Sites setting:
[image: Sites setting]

Access to the page for the guest user.
[image: Visualforce access]

Comment: This could likely be because the VF page is trying to display an error, but you're not authorized to see the default error pages. Try to view the VF page outside of Site - i.e. go to the actual platform Setup -> Develop -> Pages and preview there. That will allow you to see the true issue which you can then debug.

Comment: @BrianMansfield the page's empty - it has nothing except of <apex:page> tags. Anyway - tried to do so, the page's empty as expected and shows no errors.

Comment: Did you try creating another page? Check if you are using right profile.

Comment: @RahulSharma it's a new page - created for testing as in http://www.tgerm.com/2010/10/debugging-sites-authorization-required.html article. Also tried another page with a simple logic related to cases - doesn't work too.

Comment: Can you try loading page with enabling development mode.

Comment: @RahulSharma enabled dev. mode. What should I look at? Nothing's changed so far :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in **Login Ip ranges** for site guest user's profile. It had several ranges and users, who experienced problem(including me), didn't have their IP in the list. Added needed IPs and sites succesfully opened.